# Синхронизация потоков в c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Господа, задался вопросом, зачем в ключевом слове lock() необходима ссылка на какой-то объект. Не долго думая, написал код для проверки того, что именно по этой ссылке блокируется, весь объект содержащий ключ, слово lock или только лишь сам метод, в котором это слово встречается. Для этого сделал класс с 2 методами, один со словом lock, другой - без. Создал 4 объекта класса, каждый из которых в разных потоках вызывает один метод с блокировкой один без блокировки. И получилась оказия.

1. Ожидаемое мною поведение, если оба метода без lock - должно быть таким, что слова будут выводиться на консоль в хаотичном порядке, однако они выводятся последовательно, вначале один поток выведет слово "Глеб", потом другой, слово "Павел" (имена моих котов) и т д.
2. Ожидаемое поведение, если в методе Thr1() есть lock, тогда вначале должно много раз вывестись 100 раз слово Глеб, а потом все остальное. Но этого не происходит, и опять все выводиться по очереди. Почему?
3. Все-таки что именно за объект блокируется в слове lock и зачем его вообще туда передавать, если и так понятно, где lock там и блокировать.

Прошу прощения за большой вопрос, но уже ни гугл, ни мсдн не помогают.

Сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class a
{
    object o = new object();
    public void Thr1()
    {
        //lock (o)
        //{
            for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Console.WriteLine("Pavel {0}", x);
            }
        //}
    }
    public void Thr2()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 25 ;x++ )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("Gleb{0}", x);
        }
    }
}
class b
{
    public static a A = new a(); Thread t; Thread t1;
    public void StartThr1()
    {
        A.Thr1();
    }
    public void StartThr2()
    {
        A.Thr2();
    }
    public b()
    {
        t = new Thread(StartThr1); t.Start(); t.Join();
        t1 = new Thread(StartThr2); t1.Start(); t1.Join();
    }
}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        b B = new b();
        b B1 = new b();
        b B2 = new b();
        b B3 = new b();
    }
}
```

Блок lock закоменчен, чтобы пробовать как с ним, так и без него. Всем спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как же. Во-первых, вы нигде этот объект не используете, который под lock.
Объект туда передается для того, чтобы никто другой его не мог изменить, пока он заблокирован каким-то потоком. То есть если во время выполнения кода:

```
public void Thr1()
{
    lock (o)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("Pavel {0}", x);
        }
    }
}
```

другой поток захочет что-то сделать с объектом `o`, он не сможет этого сделать, будет ждать пока объект освободится.

Касательно того, почему вывод последовательный, у вас же потоки стартуют последовательно:

```
t = new Thread(StartThr1); t.Start(); t.Join();
t1 = new Thread(StartThr2); t1.Start(); t1.Join();
```

Попробуйте так:

```
t = new Thread(StartThr1); 
t1 = new Thread(StartThr2); 
t.Start(); 
t1.Start(); 
t.Join();
t1.Join();
```

Answer (score 2):

Из MSDN в параметр Lock передается ключ который будет определяться был ли он ранее блокирован с помощью Lock или нет.

```
lock("BLOCK_THIS") // Блокировка для любого следующего lock("BLOCK_THIS")
{ //my code 
}
lock(typeof(MyClass)) // Блокировка для любого следующего lock(typeof(MyClass))
{ // my code
}
lock(ObjectName) // Блокировка для любого следующего lock(ObjectName)
{ // my code
}
```

В отличии от блокировки по объекту, для всех остальных вариантов может возникнуть проблема того что этот ключ блокировки используется в другом участке кода, который не должен был пересекаться с текущей блокировкой и зависеть от нее.